# Multiplying a Complex Double with a Double in Haskell

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I was a bit surprised when the following code wouldn't compile:

```
-- Code 1
import Complex
type Velocity = Complex Double
type Force = Complex Double
type FrictionCoeff = Double

frictionForce :: FrictionCoeff -> Velocity -> Force
frictionForce mu vel = mu * vel
```

The error says

```
Couldn't match expected type `Complex Double'
            with actual type `Double'
Expected type: Force
Actual type: FrictionCoeff
In the first argument of `(*)', namely `mu'
In the expression: mu * vel
```

So, in short

```
-- Code 2
let z = 1 :+ 2
z * 3     -- Goes fine.
z * 2.5   -- Goes fine.
z * (2.5 :: Double)  -- Explodes.
```

Complex defines (*) as

```
instance  (RealFloat a) => Num (Complex a)  where
    (x:+y) * (x':+y') =  (x*x'-y*y') :+ (x*y'+y*x')
```

Why can 3 (Num a => a) and 2.5 (Fractional a => a) be pattern-matched against (x:+y), but a Double cannot ?

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with pattern matching. *Unification* may be the right term. You can say that `Num a => a` is unifiable with `Complex Double`, but `Double` is not.

Comment: What are you doing with complex velocities anyway? Looks like a workaround for something that should really be a vector.

Comment: Complex are built-in and come with very handy functions to get the phase, the magnitude and all.  I don't feel like re-inventing the wheel.  Is there a library for 2D vectors I could use?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First off, the type of the multiplication operator is

```
(*) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

which means that **you can only multiply numbers of the same type**, which is why multiplying a `Complex Double` by a `Double` won't work.

So why does multiplying a complex number with a decimal literal work?

It works because numeric literals are polymorphic in Haskell, so when you type an integer literal like `42`, it really means `fromInteger 42`. Similarly, decimal literals like `2.3` becomes `fromRational (23 % 10)`. If you examine the types of those functions,

```
fromInteger :: Num a => Integer -> a
fromRational :: Fractional a => Rational -> a
```

this means that integer literals can be any numeric type, while decimal literals can be any fractional type. Complex numbers are both, which is why both `z * 3` and `z * 2.5` work.

When you aren't dealing with literals, you have to convert. For example, your original function can be fixed by writing:

```
frictionForce :: FrictionCoeff -> Velocity -> Force
frictionForce mu vel = (mu :+ 0) * vel
```

Finding the appropriate conversion function is easy using [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/), since you can search for functions by type. In this case, searching for `Double -> Complex Double` gives `(:+)` as the top result.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot multiply a real number with a complex number, even in "real math"; when you want to take `2 * (2 + 3i)`, what you actually calculate is `(2 + 0i) * (2 + 3i)`. Similarly, in Haskell, when you say:

```
let z = 1 :+ 2
z * 3
```

... then 3 gets converted into a `Complex Double` as well, making the imaginary part zero. This only happens for literal numbers (`2`, `3.141` etc) because of Haskell's overloaded literal functionality; since literals don't have a default type (they can represent values of any number type), Haskell can say that the `3` has type `Complex Double` in this context, and appropriate conversion functions are called automatically.

If you want to do this conversion manually, that is, make a complex number out of a real number that is a variable or otherwise already has a different fixed type, you have to use the `realToFrac` function, which converts any real number into any fractional number (and a `Complex` counts as a fractional number in this case).

```
z * realToFrac (2.5 :: Double)
```

You can of course also manually append `:+ 0` if that looks neater to you.

Comment: I don't think that's true. 2 + 0i is the same as 2! In "real math" the reals are a subring of the complex reals, so it just works. It Haskell, you can express this relationship, but you need to be explicit about the injection. Basically that's because we don't have subtypes in Haskell, so we represent inclusion by an explicit morphism.

Comment: A complex number is a number which can be put in the form a + bi, where a and b are real numbers and i is called the imaginary unit, where i^2 = −1. The multiplication of two complex numbers is defined by the following formula: `(a+bi)(c+di)=(ac-bd)+(bc+ad)i`. So the complex numbers form a ring that is the inner product of R^2 as you say; however, multiplication is only defined between two complex numbers consisting of a pair of real numbers, so even though `2` and `2+0i` are equal, one cannot compute the product of a complex number and the real number `2` without changing the definition.

Comment: "A complex number is a number which can be put in the form _a_ + _b⋅i_, where _a_ and _b_ are real numbers" exactly. And since 0 is the neutral element of addition, _a_ + 0 _i_ = _a_ ∊ ℝ. So multiplication between a complex and a real number is mathematically sound. How is it necessary to change the definition, if we can just write any real number _a_ as _a_ + 0 _i_ ?

Comment: Because you have to rewrite the number before you do the multiplication, as you say. This is a discussion about semantics that don't matter; `a` and `a+0i` are equal but not identical which was the point I was trying to make.

Comment: "A complex number is a number which can be put in the form a + bi" -- 2 can be put in this form.

Comment: Yes, but it isn't already in that form which is the distinction I'm trying to explain. This discussion is getting more and more silly; if this is so very important to you, please start a discussion thread in some other forum about it.